# custom knockout validation for 2 dropdowns

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

How can I write a custom rule using knockout validation so two dropdowns trigger the same error message?  The dropdown default values are -1 as you can see below but I'm struggling to get the error message working for both.  The error message is correctly showing for the first dropdown (self.select1) when the value is -1 but I can't get it working for the second dropdown as well (self.select2)

**view-model**

```
self.select1 = ko.observable('-1');
self.select2 = ko.observable('-1');
```

**mark up**

```
<div data-bind="css: { valid: (select1.isModified() && select1.isValid()), requiredText: (select1.isModified() && !select1.isValid())}">
    <select data-bind="options: xxx1, optionsText: 'value', optionsValue: 'name', value: select1, event:{blur: function(){select1.isModified(true);}}"></select>
</div>    

<div data-bind="css: { valid: (select2.isModified() && select2.isValid()), requiredText: (select2.isModified() && !select2.isValid())}">
    <select data-bind="options: xxx2, optionsText: 'value', optionsValue: 'name', value: select2, event:{blur: function(){select2.isModified(true);}}"></select>
</div>
```

**error message**

```
<div class="LV_validation_message_wrapper">
    <span role="alert" class="LV_validation_message " data-bind="if: select1.isModified() && !select1.isValid(),
                style: { display: select1.isModified() && !select1.isValid() ?'block':'none' }, 
                attr: { title: select1.error }, validationMessage: select1" title="error message" style="display: block;">error message</span>
</div>
```

Comment: are you looking for required field validation ? help me understand

Answer (score 0):

you can look into this tried in a simple approach which is readable and easy to understand

see working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/57/)

**Sample view model :**

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.choiceval =ko.observable("");
    self.numberval =ko.observable("");
    var choices = [
        { id: 1, name: "one" },
        { id: 2, name: "two" },
        { id: 3, name: "three" }
    ];
     var numbers = [
        { id: 1, name: "one" },
        { id: 2, name: "two" },
        { id: 3, name: "three" }
    ];

    self.choices = ko.observableArray(choices);
    self.numbers = ko.observableArray(numbers);



    self.Validation = ko.validatedObservable([
        self.numberval.extend({ required: true }),
         self.choiceval.extend({ required: true })

    ]);


}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: thanks but this example shows each dropdown having it's own corresponding error message.  I need the two dropdowns to only have one message.

Comment: i.e. a credit card could have 2 dropdowns for the expiry date, month and year.  But the one message would say 'please enter a valid expiry date'